# How to change Data Type with using Case Statement

Tags: oracle, date, select, type-conversion

I have a code like this

```
SELECT CASE 
              WHEN gift_club_end_date = ' ' THEN ' '
              WHEN gift_club_end_date = '00000000' THEN ' '
              ELSE TO_DATE(gc.gift_club_end_date, 'yyyymmdd')

              END

       FROM gift_clubs gc
```

The error is

ORA-00932; inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE

The datatype of gift_club_end_date is VARCHAR2.

I would like to change to DATE

For example if there is row

20160802

THEN it shows

8/2/2016

but There are some rows are blank and 00000000

so I want to show/change to Blank on these rows, if blank or 00000000

How can I code like that without causing error

Thank you so much

Comment: Are you using a single space (`' '`) to signify null?  AND: What do you want the query to return - a string or a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the following:

```
with gift_clubs(gift_club_end_date) as
(
    select '20160802' from dual union all
    select '00000000' from dual union all
    select null       from dual
)
select case
        when gift_club_end_date = '00000000'
            then to_date(null)
        when gift_club_end_date is null
            then to_date(null)
        when gift_club_end_date = ' '
            then to_date(null)
        else
            to_date(gift_club_end_date, 'yyyymmdd')
       end
from gift_clubs
```

This considers the case of null and of a string containing a single space; you probably need only one of these, so edit the statement accordingly.